# Zizaco Entrust Error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using both Zizaco Confide and Entrust in my project. Focusing on Entrust, it works perfectly except for routing filter.

For example, this code works fine:

```
$user = User::find(2);
$result = $user->hasRole('Admin');
var_dump($result);    
// Returns false / true
```

but when in my filters.php I set

```
Entrust::routeNeedsRole( 'admin', 'Admin', Redirect::to('/home') );
```

I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::hasRole()
```

in Entrust.php:40 (return $user->hasRole( $permission );)

I do use PHP 5.4 and the "use HasRole;" (HasRole trait) in my User Model.

Trying to debug the error, I noticed that in the Entrust.php file, at line 36, the $this->user() method returns a GenericUser instance, that can't have the hasRole() method. I suppose it should instead return a User model..

Thanks in advance!